# Unable to create .pyd file after "cythonize hello.pyx" command

Tags: cython

I have created a hello.pyx file (which contains a function that prints "hello something"). Now I use the command "cython hello.pyx". It is showing "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat". I checked the current directory . It's creating the hello.c file . But it's not creating the hello.pyd file. Is there something wrong with the location of  msvc9compiler.py ?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617830/4657412) has the simplest and most reliable advice: use `setuptools` instead of `distutils` and it often works

Comment: @DavidW Thanks a ton for the answer . Helped a lot. I still have one problem though. While following the procedures described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617830/4657412  , I successfully arrived at the 3rd step which is the command "python setup.py build" and then install. Now it is saying it has no module named Cython. I am working in Visual studio 2008 cmd prompt and the current directory is where setup.py resides.Tried using "pip install cython". But didn't work.

Comment: This will probably be dune to the PYTHONPATH environmental variable not being set in the visual studio command prompt. Find out what it is in the command prompt you were using before and replicate it